# How to use Microsoft.Web.Deployment to operate MsDeploy how to preview file changes

Tags: c#, .net, iis, msbuild, msdeploy

When I use the MsDeploy in the way of using Microsoft.Web.Deployment to meet a problem, my C# program can work normally, the use of contentPath providers will be the site of the normal file synchronization to the server, but do not know what the contents are synchronous, know only to increase a few questions, delete some files and delete. Several problems. But I would like to know what specific documents, get a list of these documents, the current use of Microsoft.Web.Deployment I do not know how to achieve the purpose, which is very important to me, please help me.
Similar to the use of Visual MsDeploy Studio, you can preview ahead of time to know what files will be updated, I want the effect is like this, please tell me how to achieve this effect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the whatif flag to find out what will be deployed/changed with MSDeploy:

```
msdeploy -whatif -verb:sync -source:contentPath=C:\Inetpub\Site1 -dest:contentPath=C:\Inetpub\Site2
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx